# Implementing Kafka inside a Java Client Library

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have a back-end application which is exposing APIs and for my clients to consume. Till now the requirement was only from Direct Frontend Dashboards. Recently I have got a client for my service that wants to consume these Apis on his backend application.

I am planning to build a client library in java for the same, which calls my APIs, and has a build in-memory cache system. Till this point everything is clear, but i want my client to have kafka as well. One way is that the backend application that wants to consume this api has Kafka Listener inside his application, the other idea that came across my mind is that what if I cant build a kakfa listner inside my client library itself. Is it a good idea to do it? Assuming that Kafka config will be present inside the backend application that is going to use my client library?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka is a backend service. If you are providing your own REST APIs for clients, then that is not used by a Spring `@KafkaListener`.

If you add your own `@KafkaListener`, then you could store that data into your own app and expose data via HTTP endpoints, sure.

But that still wouldn't solve how external services plan on using Kafka on their own. If both services are connected same Kafka cluster, then you don't need HTTP endpoints, rather you would use `KafkaTemplate` to send data to Kafka, after which the external service would consume via their own `@KafkaListener`

Comment: I think I was unable to make my point properly with the question! What I am saying is that the client library will not only have the Rest-Api calls to my backend service but also a kafka listener which will be useful when i want to send across information about any change on the backed from my end. 
So the library that I am providing to others has rest calls for my backend and also a kafka listener which send across the necessary information to the users if any. On my actual backend I have a Kafka topic and a producer which will send this data. 
Hope its much more clean now? @OneCricketeer

Comment: Not really, sorry. Any java web app can just as easily have Kafka clients. A listener doesn't send. A KafkaTemplate / producer does, as answered.